# Metodo para alinear cabecera (HEADER) y detalle de un jTable en java

Tags: java, netbeans, jtable

Solicito de su ayuda en un caso en particular. Quisiera poder centrar la cabecera (`JTableHeader`) de un `JTable` utilizando un método. A continuación se los dejo lo que ya realice para centrar las columnas del detalle del `JTable`.

```
public static void alineacionColumnaCentrada(JTable tbl, int colum) {
    DefaultTableCellRenderer cellRender = new DefaultTableCellRenderer();
    cellRender.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    tbl.getColumnModel().getColumn(colum).setCellRenderer(cellRender);       
}
```

Como ven a través de parámetros `tbl` que es la tabla y `column` que es el numero de la columna, puedo darle la alineación a las columnas, pero ahora quisiera saber como puedo hacer lo mismo pero para la cabecera (`JTableHeader`)

Answer (score 0):

La solución más inmediata es obteniendo el *renderer* del `JTableHeader` de la tabla via `getTableHeader().getDefaultRenderer()`para luego sí aplicarle el centrado; entonces en algún lugar del código hay que incluir algo similar a esto:

```
((DefaultTableCellRenderer) miTabla.getTableHeader().getDefaultRenderer())
                       .setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
```

No lo incluyo dentro del método `alineacionColumnaCentrada` porque asumo que se va a ejecutar múltiples veces y para alinear los encabezados solo es necesaria una vez.